# integration of $\int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{\sin^{1/2}x\cos^{7/2}x}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{\sin^{1/2}x\cos^{7/2}x}$$
We got this integral problem here, now fractional powers are causing trouble in substitution. 
So I tried substituting for both $\sin^{1/2}x$ and $\cos^{7/2}x$ but that is't enough to do this problem. I guess some kind of rearreangement in the terms in required to solve this problem, but I am not able to figure it what and how. Can you give me a clue on this one ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Substitute $\tan x=z$. Then the integral becomes $$\int \frac{(1+z^2)}{\sqrt{z}}dz=2\sqrt{z}+\frac{2}{5}z^{5/2}+c=2\sqrt{\tan x}+2/5\tan^{5/2} x+c$$

Comment: Generalization:

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sin^mx\cos^{2n+2-m}x}=\int\frac{\sec^{2n}x\sec^2xdx}{\tan^mx}dx$$

Putting $\tan x=u,\sec^2xdx=du$

$$\implies I=\int\frac{(1+u^2)^n}{u}du$$

Answer (score 1):

To add details to the above answer:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sin^{1/2}(x)\cos^{7/2}(x)} = \frac{1}{\tan^{1/2}(x)\cos^{4}(x)}$$

Now put $\tan(x) = z$ as suggested above and use that $\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x) = sec^{2}(x)$ and the fact that $\sec^{2}(x) = 1 + \tan^{2}(x)$. Then the integral becomes

$$ \int \frac{(1+z^{2})dz}{z^{1/2}}$$

and now proceed as in above example.