# Calculating $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-1)^7}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the integral
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-1)^7}}.
$$
I know that the answer is
$$
\frac3{16}(3x-5)\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^4}}+C;
$$
this led me to the idea of introducing the new variable
$$
t^3=\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^4}.
$$
But that got me nowhere, because I can't express $x$ in terms of $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $t^3=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$. Then, $x=\frac{t^3+1}{t^3-1}$, $dx= -\frac{6t^2}{(t^3-1)^2}dt$ and

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-1)^7}}dx\\
=&-\frac34 \int (t^3-1)dt = -\frac3{16}t^4 +\frac34t +C\\
= & -\frac3{16}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^{\frac43} +\frac34 \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1} \right)^{\frac13} +C\\
=& \frac3{16}(3x-5)\sqrt[3]{\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^4}}+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=-\cos2t$

$$\int\dfrac{\sin t\cos t\ dt}{\sin^{4/3}t\cos^{14/3}t}=\int\dfrac{dt}{\sin^{1/3}t\cos^{11/3}t}$$

Utilise my comment in [integration of $\int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{\sin^{1/2}x\cos^{7/2}x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482888/integration-of-int-fracdx-sin1-2x-cos7-2x)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Start slowly with, for example,
$$u=\sqrt[3]{x+1}\implies x=u^3-1 \implies I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-1)^7}}=3\int\frac{du}{\sqrt[3]{\left(u^3-2\right)^7}}$$

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer because I don't know how to calculate $\int\frac{du}{\sqrt[3]{\left(u^3-2\right)^7}}$